# Definition of "fixed point" for binary operator

Tags: definition, binary-operations

What is a term for a value $x \in X$ that for binary operator $f\colon X\times X \to X$ maps always to itself, no matter what is the other value
$$
\forall y \in X \quad f(x, y) = f(y, x) = x
$$

Is it called ["fixed point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) too or not?

Examples are $0$ for [numbers multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication), $\mathrm{false}$ for [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), $\mathrm{true}$ for [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), $\emptyset$ for [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), etc.

Comment: I have seen such elements called "absorbing".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: thanks a lot, according to [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element) it is what I was looking for, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such elements are often called **absorbing elements**. In semigroup theory it is often called the identity or zero element.

see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absorbing_element
https://planetmath.org/absorbingelement